# TextWatcher afterTextChanged()'s Editable.replace() does not replace text in EditText properly

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textwatcher

In the Android app, I have an `EditText` which should replace certain strings with values from app data.

for e.g. if user types `$username` it should get replaced with the name of whichever user is currently logged in.

The `Editable` parameter in `afterTextChanged()` method of `TextWatcher` applied on `EditText` replaces the `$username` with correct value but the problem is that after the `$username` is replaced with actual username if I press any character after that it is appended with `username` followed by pressed character.

e.g.

Say current logged in username is `Joe`

a. if the input is `Hi this is @username`

b. `afterTextChanged()` changes it to `Hi this is Joe`

c. Now if I press any other character(say I press g OR space) then text in `EditText` changes to `Hi this is Joeusernameg` OR `Hi this is Joeusername`

How do I get output as in step `b`?

```
etTemplateMessage.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            final String strUserNameCode = "$username";
            String text = s.toString();
            if(text.contains(strUserNameCode)){
                int startIndex = text.indexOf(strUserNameCode);
                int endIndex = startIndex + strUserNameCode.length();
                Editable profileName = new SpannableStringBuilder(FileUtil.getUTF8String(settingDTO.getProfileName()));
                s.replace(startIndex, endIndex, profileName);
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

on your afterTextChange method you should set text to the edit text. And String has replace(CharSequence old, CharSequence new) method you can also use it.
like this,

```
PublishSubject publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();
        publishSubject.debounce(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(query -> onTextChanged(query.toString()));


void onTextChanged(String text){
 final String strUserNameCode = "$username";
     etTemplateMessage.setText(text.replace(strUserNameCode, FileUtil.getUTF8String(settingDTO.getProfileName())));
}
```

and on your aftertextChange method call `publishSubject.onNext( s.toString())`

- Note that you can achieve this with RxJava.

Comment: I already tried this. When is set etTemplateMessage.setText() inside afterTextChanged() the app hangs as soon as I hit/ type `e` in $username.

Any ideas?

Comment: You can do this with rxjava. You can create PublishSubject object and configure it with debounce 200 milliseconds. And when you stop typing it will be work only that time. I will update my answer so you can see it.

Comment: My fault. Your solution works. I was calling text.replace() function just before etTemplateMessage.setText(). Hence the replaced text got ignored and the text in `EditText` never changed. But since I called `setText()` method and the text never changed. It went into an infinite loop since `setText() fires text changed event`.

Thanks. `PublishSubject` was not required.

Comment: Good to know it.